# Applications not Focusing when Launched

Tags: gnome, 20.10

I have never had this problem before until today. When I press <kbd>Super</kbd> and then search for the application I want, I can usually just hit enter and then the application launches and appears on the screen. Now, whenever I hit enter with the application selected, it just sends me back to the current application I am on and then sends me a notification like this:
[image: Image of Notification with text '"Untitled 1 - LibreOffice Writer" is ready']

I have tried solutions from questions like this one, [When I launch an app, the focus doesn't move to the opened app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128738/when-i-launch-an-app-the-focus-doesnt-move-to-the-opened-app/130349#130349) to no avail. I would appreciate any assistance.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the Gnome Shell extension "No Annoyance" to get rid of this behavior, and have your launched window focused automatically.

• You can **install** the extension using the software center or using the terminal command:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-no-annoyance
```

• You then need to **enable** the extension. To that aim, either install Extensions (`gnome-shell-extension-prefs`), or Tweaks (`gnome-tweaks`). Both tools allow to enable or disable Gnome Shell extensions.

Comment: Thank you! This helped and I marked it as the answer.